# Should filter share code with webapi controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a webapi Authorize filter which does some security checks on the queryString for "Get" calls.

For post methods, since I need to peek at the payload to retrieve the object (moreover, that would make my filter dependent upon my dtos, which I'm not a huge fan either...), and since I didn't find an easy way to open the post payload in the filter, I ended the subject by making the check in a controller method.
Obviously, the logic is the same in both cases.

So I put the validation logic in an abstract controller and make it "public static" so they can be called from the filter and from all inheriting controllers. I've read the google results from the follwoing query (avoiding calling static methods), and truth be told, I also find this ugly and untestable.

But what would be an **elegant** alternative ?

I've considered creating a (static ?) helper class but I only find it's syntactic sugar around the same concept.
I also think that helpers should not be IOc'ed maybe I'm wrong here ?

Thanks for your input !

Comment: It's hard to make judgements without code. Based on your description, I would make the utility method a static method in a static class and treat it as implementation detail of the users of that method (and don't inject it). As long as the utility method is stateless, it's still testable if it's declared in this way. Definitely wouldn't recommend an abstract class here.

Comment: @Dan, I followed your queue, happened that, going to the end of it, I needed more methods than I originally thought, thus a static helper was not overkill after all. I would mark your comment as answer if that were possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You should include the details of validations that you wanna do on the query string to help us understand the problem in more details. However based on the information provided I have following to say.

Creating a static method in Controllers and accessing it in Filters is more ugly than exposing DTOs to Authorize Filter. The controllers acts as service layer and Filters are (to some extent) part of it(service layer) too. So there is nothing wrong if you have to expose DTOs to Filters. It can simply be seen as "DTOs being exposed to service layer".

However, if you really wish to avoid it, put an abstraction as part of your service layers which can be exposed to the Filters. Like you can create a interface (and its implementations) that exposes a validation method for your purpose that can be consumed from within the Authorize Filter.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I disagree on this point : controller is not service layer.

Comment: I assumed your controllers are WebApi Controllers. However, even if it is an MVC Controller and the meaning changes, my argument holds true. The action and Controllers are part of same purpose.

Comment: Your assumption was correct, controllers are WebApi Controllers however, in my opinion, The controller layer has nothing to do with Service Layers, they are two completely different entities with their own set of responsibilities.

Comment: You're right ! I had totally forgotten webapi signature was considered as the service. I only considered service as the layer atop the dal and controller as a technical layer between UI and Service. But the controller defines the interface thus it is part of the service. Thank you for correcting  me :)